# Team Build Error: The Path ... is already mapped to workspace 

Tags: tfs, build-server

When creating a new build in Team Foundation Server, I get the following error when attempting to run the new build:

> The path
>   C:\Build\ProductReleases\FullBuildv5.4.2x\Sources
>   is already mapped to workspace
>   BuildServer_23.

I am unable to see a workspace by that name in the workspaces dialog.

Comment: This is more complicated error, see [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322604/team-build-the-path-path-is-already-mapped-in-workspace-workspace-error-even/4681908#4681908).

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use the command line utility *TF - Team Foundation Version Control Tool* (**tf**).

You can get a list of all workspaces by bringing up a *Visual Studio Command Prompt* then changing to your workspace folder and issuing the following commands:

```
C:\YourWorkspaceFolder>tf workspaces /owner:*
```

You should see your problem workspace in the list as well as it's owner.

You can delete the workspace with the following command:

```
C:\YourWorkspaceFolder>tf workspace /delete /server:BUILDSERVER WORKSPACENAME;OWNERNAME
```

Comment: I'm getting "Unable to determine the source control server." when running tf workspaces on the build server. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Corvin: run the command from within the folder that is part of the workspace

Comment: Leave off the /server argument, it's not needed. Otherwise good answer!

Comment: Great answer, only thing I would add is you may need to sign into TFS as the owner of the workspace, or you may get a permission denied error.

Comment: I had this problem as I moved our builds from the UpgradeTemplate to the DefaultTemplate.  I had workspaces of the format <build agent>_<build id #>_<decoded uri #> mapping to the <build name>\Sources directories.  After the upgrade I then had <build id #>_<decoded uri #>_<build agent> mapping to the same sources directories.  

During the build TFS was unable to find & delete the old workspace so it errored out when trying to create it.  The solution, as mentioned here, was to delete the old workspaces.  Just adding this bit of info in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Note to **git-tfs** users: this answer can solve problems with using TFS through Git as well.

Comment: After /delete, I entered "/collection:http:<server>:808/tfs/<collection> ..._then_ the workspacename;workspaceowner... worked as expected.  My issue was due to re-creating a build definition by the same name.

Comment: `tf workspace delete` certainly pointed me in the right direction. However, it did not work for my particular situation because the workspace I wanted to remove was mapped to a TFS collection that had been taken offline. What I did find effective however, was [clearing the cache](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24599533/1497596) (specfically, removing the GUID-named subfolders) and then editing **LocationServerMap.xml**, **ServerMap.xml**, and **VersionControl.config**.

Comment: If you have a convoluted workspace setup like me where you access TFS servers with different windows credentials, you may find that you can view but not delete workspaces that were created with different windows credentials. Delete the TFS connection, launch the Credential Manager and change your credentials in each of the two entries for your TFS server, then re-connect. Now you can delete workspaces under that account.

Comment: /server:{localhost, buildservername, fully.qualified.buildservername} did nothing for me. when I dropped that it worked.

Comment: I wasn't able to delete the workspace as I got the response "Select one workspace". I then deleted the build definition and created a new one which also solved the problem

Comment: @RajRao I'm having the same issue as @Corvin, but when I try to run the command from the command from any folder other than /Common7/IDE, I get `'tf' is not recognized as an internal or external command...`. Any ideas?

Comment: When listing the workspaces (all 1562 of them) the "owner" was listed as a nice `Last, First` format, but using that in the delete threw the error `TF10158: The user or group name Last, First contains unsupported characters, is empty, or too long.` I had to use the short login name.

Answer (score 60):

Just delete the contents of the following folder(s):

**C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache**

Where UserName is actual or current user, and 3.0 is the version number.

Comment: This answer had been given a few times already, with more explanation, in a couple times years ago.

Comment: this is what I needed. I deleted all references with tf command and also with sidekicks but I still needed to remove this cache. thank you, thank you, thank you

Comment: Specifically, you can remove the offending workspace's `WorkspaceInfo` entry from `C:\Users\ukcco3jbe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache\VersionControl.config`.  XPath: `/VersionControlServer/Servers/ServerInfo/WorkspaceInfo`

Comment: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0          for vs2019

Answer (score 40):

I had a similar issue and to remove the workspace that was causing me a problem, I logged into another machine with TFS client installed and performed the following:

- On the **File** menu, point to **Source Control**, **Advanced**, and then click
  **Workspaces...**.
- In the **Manage Workspaces** dialog box, tick the **Show remote packages** checkbox.
- Under the **Name** column, select the workspace that you want to remove, and then click **Remove**.
- In
  the **Confirmation** dialog box, click **OK**.

Comment: My workstation was listed twice.  Removed the duplicate and it immediately worked.  Thanks.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer!

Answer (score 31):

I received this error, which was caused by having two build definitions that pointed to the same source.  The issue was that I used a static build directory in the Build Agent.

This forum post describes my issue and resolution exactly:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/60a4138a-9b28-4c46-bdf4-f9775ce43c3e/

Answer (score 28):

We had the same problem but deleting the workspace's from the TFS server did not work. 
(I should mention that I grabbed my colleagues VM that was already set up with his credentials.)

For me this worked:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/12/path-is-already-mapped-in-workspace.aspx

I just went into the : ...\Local Settings\Application Data\ made a search for VersionControl.config, opened up the folder that contained this file and deleted all of it's contents.

Previous to that I tried manually editing the file but it continued with the same error message.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Was helpful for our situation, where we switched servers and the old server didn't exist anymore, but an old machine still had settings for it.

Comment: I had to do this too. I deleted the entire `Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation` folder and all was well afterwards

Comment: It is the cache, simply delete the Cache folder(s)

Comment: I deleted the workspace and the cache folder, but the issue is still there. Maybe jenkins is running under a different user and uses another cache?

Comment: It probably is! There are all sorts of plugins that you can use to clean u your workspace before the actual build starts. If you find the answer for this particular problem, please come back and post it here so that others can benefit from it as well :)

Comment: This solution works after you delete a TFS connection yet it is still complaining that that folder is mapped so you are unable to map to a different connection/project/whatever.

Comment: For those who don't know where `...\Local Settings` is, the folder on my Windows Server 2012 box appears to be `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation`, where `%userprofile%` is the user your agent is running under.

Answer (score 18):

For some reason I was having trouble deleting the workspace from the command-line utility.  Luckily I found [Team Foundation Sidekicks 2010](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2010) (from [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/dd2391e4-1941-4d64-bf70-90d60b045c9a/)) which is free and provides a GUI for viewing and deleting TFS workspaces, and many more useful TFS features.

Comment: I strongly suggest anyone that work with TFS to have a look at TFS Sidekicks, because it is free and has a lot of really must-have features.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem with Visual Studio 2010 complaining about an already-mapped-workspace, but instead of deleting the entire workspace, I used the following from the Visual Studio Command Prompt: "tf workspace PROBLEM_WORKSPACE_NAME". This brought up an "Edit Workspace" dialog.  From there I was able to remove the path in question from the "Working Folders" list, which got rid of the error.

Comment: Your solution helped me in a similar case. I've created a workspace for the wrong user, so I deleted it and then attempted to create it for the right one, but `tf` complained that the path was associated with another workspace -- the one I deleted. Inspired by your reply, I recreated the workspace for the wrong user, deleted only the association with the path and finally I succeeded in creating the workspace for the right user.

Answer (score 8):

the rest was fairly easy.

Simply go to this folder: 
C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4\Cache 
and delete all that's in the folder.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting an exception telling me that the file was already mapped in another workspace:
**"The path {File Path} is already mapped in workspace {Workspace Name}."**

This workspace was **deleted beofre**.
With the help of friend of mine I found out that TFS save workspace info under the user local settings dir. We found a file named:

**VersionControl.config** under **{User Documents and Settings dir}\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\1.0\Cache.**
This file contains all the local mapping of TFS. Probably when you use the Map method and don't use:
public void DeleteMapping(WorkingFolder mapping); before deleting the workspace the mapping information is not removed from this file which is used by TFS to check if you've alreay mapped a specific path.

**To resolve this problem delete all the keys from the config file. Don't delete the file because you'll get it again from the server cache.**

Comment: This worked for me; I had to remove ALL keys.  There were 3 such file so I just edited all 3.  NOTE:  The directory structure has changed since this answer was written.  Also, @Morteza, while I appreciate your answer, it is really too bad that Microsoft didn't come up with an elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I did (well what I do):

Using TFS Sidekicks clear out the user and server filters so they are blank. This will let you get all workspaces.

Check the build error for the workspace name. In the OPs case it is BuildServer_23. It is different in my environment but basically just match up the error name with the one in the tfs sidekick list.

Click the red x to delete the workspace.

Viola!

Answer (score 3):

If applicable, you can also clone the build definition and change its name.  This workded for me.

Comment: Thanks for this. The combination of deleting the cache folder and (re)-cloning my build definition fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the following solutions such as :

1. Use sidekicks to delete WS.
2. Use tf commands to delete remote server workspaces.
3. Delete the TFS cache folder.

The following worked for me:

```
tf workspaces /remove:*
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have permissions on the server to delete other people's workspaces, you can just change the name of the build definition. TFS will create a new workspace and map it to "C:\Build\ProductReleases\new build name here\Sources".

Answer (score 2):

While trying to 'Get latest version' of a project which I had previously mapped to a local directory and then deleted, I saw this same error message.
First I tried the SideKick tool and then the Visual Studio 2010 command prompt, both of which told me I had no workspaces mapped.

Next I searched for 'VersionControl.config' within `c:/users/myuser/appdata`, and deleted the 4 references it found.
I re-opened Visual Studio and I was able to re-map the project, no more error!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to do this is to go to your AppData and delete the TFS cache (depending on the version 3.0 or 4.0)

C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache 
or 
C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache

Comment: After doing the workspaces clean up with VS and TFS sidekick tool, this manual approach of deleting the cache worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

TDN's solution worked for me when I was having the same issue. The Build server created workspaces under my account. Checking this box allowed me to see and delete them.

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue in Visual Studio 2017 and TFS 2017. DefaultCollection must be mapped first to you local path. Somehow this step was skipped and I got only MyFirstProject mapped.

[image]

All you need to do is: 
**- 1.** Go to your TFS web page and remove the project from the server.

[image]

**- 2.** Remove the project from your local "Worksapces"

[image]

**- 3.** Go to "Manage Connections" which will refresh your Home page in TeamExplorer.

[image]

**- 4.** You will get Configuration page which will allow you to setup root path to your DefaultCollection.

[image]

**- 5.** You should get message that it been done successfully. Now you can create your project.

[image]

**It's important to map root of your collection to your workspace first and then map a new project.**

Answer (score 2):

My issue was related to using multiple accounts.  This is how I was able to switch accounts.

Open **Team Explorer**

From the big drop down menu near the top of the pane...

Navigate to:
**Projects and my Teams**>**Manage Connections**

Navigate to:
**Manage Connections**>**Connect to Team Project**

Use the "Switch User" link to switch accounts.

Now the workspace names will match the chosen account.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get any other solution to work.

I had a new account created and the old account no longer had permissions (both on same machine).

I tried:
1) Deleting the workspace (couldn't see in VS with or without remote workspaces checked)
2) Deleting from the command line
3) New owner command
4) Deleting the cache

So I simply opened VS as admin and mapped to a different folder.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the workspace and cache was not sufficient for me.
I had to also restart the "Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host" service.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Source Control Explorer
2. In the toolbar there is a dropdown list of Workspaces.
3. Click the dropdown and go to workspaces.
4. Remove the unwanted workspace.
5. Map to your local.

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
Build Definition -> Workspace -> Build Agent Folder
```

from

```
c:\some\path
```

to

```
$(SourceDir)
```

and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with this with Azure DevOps automated builds in an on-prem TFS build agent. Removing the workspace using TFS Sidekicks did not work. And tf.exe could not even find the workspace to delete it.

This solution should work for TFS 2017, TFS 2018, Azure DevOps, and possibly other versions:

1. Take note of the workspace GUID in the error message.
2. On the machine where the build is taking place, navigate to:  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\ (where %USERPROFILE% belongs to the user that triggered the build).
3. Search for and remove all instances of the workspace GUID under that directory.  There will likely be a folder in a 'cache' directory, as well as entries in 'LocationServerMap.xml' and 'LocalItemExclusions.config'. Remove them all.

That worked in my circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the workspace:

```
workspace /delete "the-workspace-name"
```