# TFS Build Fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We run TFS 2008 and Visual Studio 2010B2 (as with any Beta, errors are predominant).

Below are the errors given (from the build log):

```
Task "DeleteWorkspaceTask" 
DeleteWorkspaceTask 
TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://dev-svr:8080/" 
BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/1679" 
Name="**ALICE_3_**" 
DeleteLocalItems=True 
TF14061: The workspace **ALICE_3_**;HELLO\TFSservice does not exist. 
Done executing task "DeleteWorkspaceTask". 

Task "DeleteWorkspaceTask" skipped, due to false condition; 
( '$(SkipInitializeWorkspace)'!='true' and ('$(CleanCompilationOutputOnly)' == 'true' or '$(SkipClean)' == 'true') ) 
was evaluated as ( 'false'!='true' and ('false' == 'true' or 'false' == 'true') ). 

Using "CreateWorkspaceTask" task from assembly 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.VersionControl.dll". 
Task "CreateWorkspaceTask" 
CreateWorkspaceTask 
TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://dev-svr:8080/" 
BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/1679" 
Name="**ALICE_3_**" 
BuildDirectory="c:\builds\science\SCIENCE\AB" 
SourcesDirectory="c:\builds\science\SCIENCE\AB\Sources" 
Comment="Workspace created by Team Build" 

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(796,5,796,5): 
error : The path c:\builds\science\SCIENCE\AB\Sources is already mapped in workspace **ALICE_3**. 
[c:\builds\science\SCIENCE\AB\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
```

Any input would be appreciated, as this area of development isn't my forte.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: This probably belongs on SF. But assuming it belongs here, what OS are the clients and server. What patch level is TFS?

Comment: Server: XP Pro /n Clients: 7 Ultimate /n I'm not sure how to check the verison on TFS

Answer (score 0):

From [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226288/team-build-error-the-path-is-already-mapped-to-workspace):

> Use the command line utility tf.
>
> You can get a list of all workspaces
>   by bringing up a Visual Studio Command
>   Prompt and using the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> c:\>tf workspaces /owner:*
> ```
>
> You should see your problem workspace
>   in the list as well as it's owner.
>
> You can delete the workspace with the
>   following command:
>
> ```
> C:\>tf workspace /delete /server:BUILDSERVER WORKSPACENAME;OWNERNAME
> ```

Comment: This looks like a reasonible solution; however I'm often cautious of deleting workspaces manually. I think I'd rather have that process automated (I think the bug exists in the actual delete workspace)

Answer (score 0):

After looking into in greater depth it looks as if the problem lies elsewhere:

```
Task "DeleteWorkspaceTask"
  DeleteWorkspaceTask TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://dev-svr:8080/" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/1679" Name="**ALICE_3_**" DeleteLocalItems=True
  TF14061: The workspace **ALICE_3_**;HELLO\TFSservice does not exist.
Done executing task "DeleteWorkspaceTask".
Task "DeleteWorkspaceTask" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(SkipInitializeWorkspace)'!='true' and ('$(CleanCompilationOutputOnly)' == 'true' or '$(SkipClean)' == 'true') ) was evaluated as ( 'false'!='true' and ('false' == 'true' or 'false' == 'true') ).
Using "CreateWorkspaceTask" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.VersionControl.dll".
Task "CreateWorkspaceTask"
  CreateWorkspaceTask TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://dev-svr:8080/" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/1679" Name="**ALICE_3_**" BuildDirectory="c:\builds\science\SCIENCE\AB" SourcesDirectory="c:\builds\science\SCIENCE\AB\Sources" Comment="Workspace created by Team Build"
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(796,5,796,5): error : The path c:\builds\science\SCIENCE\AB\Sources is a
```

lready mapped in workspace **ALICE_3**. [c:\builds\science\SCIENCE\AB\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]

My initial thought was that the build attempted to delete a workspace which does not (yet) exist, however it would appear that it does exist and just failed to delete the previous verison of the build due to a mapping error. Any ideas as to where I can change this?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

This can still happen with TFS 2010 if you change the build server account. In this case it is probably best to clear out the old workspaces.