# What causes TFS to create additional workspaces?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I've seen [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226288/team-build-error-the-path-is-already-mapped-to-workspace) related to the error message you get from TFS when a workspace is already mapped.  The accepted answer for removing the workspace is alright as a workaround, but it's already getting tedious to run a delete command each time this error occurs.

What do I need to change in order to get out of having to use this workaround?  I've got two builds (continuous integration and nightly deploy), and need to add at least one more build type.  I followed [this URL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/60a4138a-9b28-4c46-bdf4-f9775ce43c3e/) to see if there was a possible resolution there, but I'm not sure I understand it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how this is accomplished in TFS 2010, as I have not gotten to work with Team Build in 2010, yet.  In 2008, though, if you expand the Builds node in the Team Project and right-right click on either of the builds, you will see a "Manage Build Agents..." option.  Click into that, and it will bring up a dialog.  One of the things on that dialog is an option called "Working Directory".  Do you have the same hard-coded path in both of them?

By default, when you create a new build definition, it provides a calculated folder for this value.  This is where the build agent will do the checkout from TFS for the build attempt.  The default value is, $(Temp)\$(BuildDefinitionPath), I believe (I am not connected to TFS at the moment).

The article you link to is basically saying that you should include either that $(BuildDefinitionPath) value or the $(BuildDefinitionID) value as part of that path in that dialog so that the two builds do not try to use the same workspace.  Changing the working folder to include one of those values should resolve your issue, going forward.

Comment: I've changed the working directory for the one build agent we have.  We'll see if that has the desired effect.