# TFS 2012 : The working folder is already in use after Hard Disk Format

Tags: team-explorer, tf-cli, source-control-explorer

I have referred to a lot of forums and also this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226288/team-build-error-the-path-is-already-mapped-to-workspace) but my problem is that I have formatted my machine. So I'm not able to overcome this issue. I have tried deleting workspaces from visual studio command prompt and also clearing cache, but I feel this mapping is more on the server-side than local cache, because my machine was formatted. I don't know which file has this old working path saved.

Also I have tried downloading the project into a new working path. I was able to download, but then I don't get the TFS icon against each file. i.e.it's like working offline (disjoint from TFS database). On right click we generally have an option to return online or go online. In this case on right click I get TEAM -> Apply Patch & TEAM -> Share Project

Please help me with this.I had the same problem in my asp.net projects, when I simply downloaded them onto a new working path it worked fine. But this java project in eclipse just doesn't seem to connect to tfs when downloaded into a new path nor does it allow to download in the old path.

Please not I have formatted the machine.So my case is different, so this may not be a possible duplicate of other SO questions.

I did not disconnect or delete workspace before a format(due to lack of knowledge) at that point. May be doing that would never cause this.
All I did is check in all files and re-formatted my windows.

Comment: `Please not I have formatted the machine.` *Please **note**…*?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'd suggest using the (free) tool TFS Sidekicks: http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

This will give you a GUI to view all workspaces (across all users and machines), and delete the obsolete ones.

[image]

Comment: For this, I will have to tell my firm to purchase sidekicks right?

Comment: using tfs sidekicks solved my issue, I deleted all working folders and their workspaces :) it's much easier with a UI

Comment: Tried running it, gives me an error saying "Application cannot read registry."

Comment: I tried this but it could not find a workspace on the current machine by a different username

Comment: Really Saved me ..Thanks

Answer (score 11):

This is stored on the server, but the `tf workspace` command should be able to remove it for you. You will probably need to supply it with the correct machine name to find it:

> `tf workspaces /computer:* /owner:domain\jesse.houwing /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

Find the missing workspace (the one that was formatted) and remove it from the server:

> `tf workspace /delete /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection workspaceName;domain\jesse.houwing`

Do not confuse `tf workspaces /remove` and `tf workspace /delete`, the former only removes the registration from your machine, the second removes it from the server.

Or, if the computer name and the username have stayed the same, edit the workspace and delete the paths no longer valid (or update them to their new location) by changing the workspace configuration.  Use

> `tf workspace workspaceName;Owner`

to open the dialog to edit your current workspace.

Or use

> `tf workspaces  /updateComputerName /updateUserName`

To reassign the workspace from the old computer (iinstallation) or user to the new one.

Comment: Hi I'm able to see one workspace in this, but I have multiple projects in that workspace. will deleting it delete all mappings?

Comment: Yes it will delete all mapped folders in that workspace

Comment: what if I want to delete some(or only one)? Because deleting all will require re-mapping all project paths again.It'll be a tedious task

Comment: Hey @jessehouwing, I deleted the workspace and took the pains of re-mapping all my projects to new working folders. This however has not resolved my problem for the eclipse android project :(

Comment: Can ou provide more information on the things you have installed, I suspect Team Explorer Everywhere (which version), Eclipse (whichversion), Android Studio (which version) and can you show the output of the above commands when executed from the CLC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490833.aspx

Comment: your answer was helpful too, but using sidekicks did the trick.Sorry I don't have much details on which version is installed, and didn't bother to get into all of that, as that is taken care by the software admin of our firm

Answer (score 5):

I tried using the TFS sidekick tool, but even then, ran into access denied error. Then I had to manually clear off the files from this path:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces
```

So this can be alternative, if you do not want to install a tool or your company does not allow you to install software from unknown sources on your laptops due to policies.

Answer (score 1):

This already has a marked answer but my problem was solved without command line or additional software.

I had just recently updated to '15 and I was migrating my workspace folder to another drive as it was getting too big. The error being uninformative as it was, still appeared even after I deleted the workspace it cited...or so i thought. Both VS'13 and '15 by default made the same named workspace but one for each version. I had to reopen '13, and delete that workspace then move back to '15 where it would now let me remap my folder.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

logout from previous user and login by new user.
Copy Project Folder to Another path.
In team Explorer Right click on project and Remove mapping.
Remap Project

Answer (score 0):

go to Control Panel --> User Accounts --> Manage your credentials --> Edit tfs User Name

user name : your TFS user.

I solved it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
TFS workspace manager throw me this error:
"The working folder \PATH\ is already in use by the workspace my_computer_name name_of_previous_user on computer my_computer_name"

**I solved this problem by creating user in TFS server and deleting the previous one.**
U can go to TEAM> TEAM PROJECT SETTINGS > SECURITY.
& if u have permission- create your own user.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get it to work using Manage Workspaces in VS:

1. Click on Show remote workspaces, delete remote workspaces as I was not using them anyway, not sure if this was needed.
2. Created a new Workspace B and mapped to another folder Y and choose yes to download all files now.
3. Deleted original workspace A, mapped to Folder X.
4. Recreate original workspace A and remap to folder Y (wrong folder) and choose Yes to download all files now.
5. Delete Workspace B
6. Edit Workspace A, go to Advanced.  At the bottom where it says Wroking Folders, change the Local Folder path back to folder X and choose yes to download all files now.

Not sure if you have to do all those steps but that is what I did to finally get this remapped, only took all day.