# Team build error: the path already mapped to workspace ... AGAIN AND AGAIN

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, build-definition

So I have reviewed the link to solve this problem, as referenced below.

[Team build error: the path already mapped to workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226288/team-build-error-the-path-is-already-mapped-to-workspace)

But my problem is that EVERY time i queue that Build Definition i get the same problem.   Ok, i go delete the tfs workspace it's complaining about.   Great it works!  Then run the build again... ok now it doesn't and i have to go delete the TFS service workspace all over again.

How come TFS build service is stepping on itself every time it does a build.  The error is " Unable to create the workspace 'xxx' due to mapping conflict... the path xxx is already mapped in workspace 'xxx'"   but the mapping is to a workspace that the previous BUILD created. Not anything from a specific user.

Comment: clean all of the generated build workspaces, it should clear your problem. to do this you can use the TFS side kicks tool

Comment: sidekick is a great tool and helped clear those tfs service workspaces... but it doesn't solve the problem if (i) use a fixed path for the build agent.  I had to do both the fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

ok, this seemed to occur because (i hadn't noticed) that i changed the "Build Agent Folder" specification by accident to a fixed path.  rather than keeping it with  $(SourceDir).   I changed the entry in the build definition to this and it worked fine, after multiple builds using same build definition.