# TFS Build Error Path already mapped to another workspace Occuring even after deleting cache file

Tags: caching, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

Firstly I read through many existing threads and followed the instructions there

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226288/team-build-error-the-path-is-already-mapped-to-workspace)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632550/team-build-error-the-path-already-mapped-to-workspace-again-and-again)

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/12/path-is-already-mapped-in-workspace.aspx)

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/02219bd6-bfc0-4412-9912-5fcc38279a82/build-fails-with-mappingconflictexception)

[Here](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2008/01/path-already-mapped-in-workspace-error.html)

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/12/path-is-already-mapped-in-workspace.aspx)

Almost all the above threads asked me to delete the cache file. I went into the machine and deleted the cache file. I even edited the cache file (XML file named version config) but still it gets overwritten

But still even after that I am seeing the same issue.

The build agent has got dynamic $SourceDir as value

What else can I do to fix this? Please Help.

I tried doing tf workspaces but it simply keeps saying that "Unable to determine the source control server"

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets (838): Unable to create the workspace 'NVM1756PDV_105_7' due to a mapping conflict. You may need to manually delete an old workspace. You can get a list of workspaces on a computer with the command 'tf workspaces /computer:%COMPUTERNAME%'. 
    Details: The path C:\Builds\7\Common_Security\cloud\src is already mapped in workspace NVM1756PDV_104_7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the **tf workspace /delete NVM1756PDV_104_7** command to correct this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/) to delete the workspace using the **Workspace Sidekick**.

Comment: thank you.i tried this.but unfortunately i didn't have access install access.