# Failed To Create Mapping , Conflicts with one of it's parent's mappings

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I created a project with visual studio 2017 and I want to add it to team foundation server but I get this error :

> Failed To create Mapping
>
> The mapping for $/sampleProject conflict with one of its parent's mapping

I was thinking it's because of duplicated name but I checked my team foundation server, there is not any project with this name.

please help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error info, the cause of this issue maybe:

When you tried to map the parent local directory to a server subdirectory, it failed as the immediate child was mapped to the server root.

If you map each project to a different local directory, may get confused with how the server mappings and client mappings sync.  To get around this, you could simply map the base server directory to a single client directory and let TFS match them up; for example:

```
c:\Dev\Workspace <--> $/
```

When you do a get latest or check in for your TFS repository, TFS will simply create any necessary directories; for example:

```
c:\Dev\Workspace \sampleProject\
```

Besides, also make sure DefaultCollection must be mapped first to you local path.

[image]

For details check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42702472/5391065).

Another method is back up your project and delete it, then create a new one, make sure the locations you have selected is under your current local workspace, also check "**Add to Source Control**".

[image]

If above is still not working, delete your old workspace (back up first), then create a new one, repeat above step, which should do the trick.